# Azure resource group deployment in azure devops failed with error ["Message": "Deployment with id '#######' exists"]

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

I am creating a rlease definition in azure devops incluging deployment of arm template using Azure resource group deployment step. 
i am getting an error that says

```
019-10-23T01:59:02.1607991Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1670193Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1678572Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1679076Z ##[error]Details:
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1679263Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Details:
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1690885Z ##[error]Conflict: {
  "Message": "Deployment with id '####' exists"
}
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1691134Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Conflict: {%0D%0A  "Message": "Deployment with id '3131571625766363' exists"%0D%0A}
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1697310Z ##[error]Conflict: {
  "Message": "Deployment with id '###' exists"
}
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1697524Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Conflict: {%0D%0A  "Message": "Deployment with id '###' exists"%0D%0A}
2019-10-23T01:59:02.1697754Z ##[error]Conflict: {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The 'Performing deployment' operation conflicts with the pending 'Performing deployment' operation started at 2019-10-23T01:58:54.0080997Z.  Please retry operation later."
  }
}
```

I tried many time and it always raises this error. I even cannot find the pending deployments on azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can view deployments by navigating to the resource group it is deploying to, unless the deployment scope type is Subsciption, Tenant or Management Group.

If it's a resource group deployment, navigate:

Portal -> Resource Groups -> Select -> Deployments

You can stop a deployment by clicking on it and selecting cancel.

You can also use powershell:

```
Stop-AzDeployment -Name 'Performing deployment'
```

Comment: it doesn't show pending deployments. it shows only succeeded and failed deployments.

Comment: Try using PowerShell's `Get-AzDeployment | Where { $_.ProvisioningState -eq "Updating" }`.  You can also pipe this to `Stop-AzDeployment` if you are happy stopping all deployments, or just use `-Name` to stop a single deployment.